# Login no Github via SSH

Tags: git, github, ssh

Bom dia!
Quando eu logo no servidor via SSH e executo o comando sss -t git@github.com, retorna uma mensagem mostrando qual usuário está logado nesse site. Minha dúvida é como eu faço login com outro usuário no Github via SSH. Já verifiquei a chave SSH no GitHub, mas não consegui trocar o usuário ainda.

Answer (score 1):

Se precisar fazer apenas uma vez

```
git push ssh://<temp_user>@<host>/<repo_path> <local_branch>:<remote_branch>
```

Se precisar de duas chaves de SSH

entra no @editoDeTextoPreferido ~/.ssh/config

```
# Default GitHub user (joe)
Host github.com
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/joe/.ssh/id_rsa

# Client user (client)
Host github-client
  HostName github.com
  User git
  IdentityFile /Users/joe/.ssh/id_rsa_client
```

aí pode usar assim

```
git clone git@github.com:joe/my_repo.git
```

e

```
git clone git@github-client:client/his_repo.git
```

O global depende do GIT que voce está usando mas o legal é conhecer o conceito de GIT Global para fazer a alteração correta para o que voce precisa.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado pela ajuda!